# How to compile changed files only in FreeBSD kernel?

Tags: compilation, kernel, freebsd

So, I'm manipulating a part of kernel. How could I avoid recompiling the whole kernel stuff? I mean, almost all the object files remain the same (except the single file I'm editing)

I tried to use `MODULES_OVERRIDE=` to avoid recompiling the modules, but there are a lot of other files (like `/usr/src/sys/dev/`) that are still being re-compiled.

How could I avoid wasting time on recompiling those files?

Comment: this is a job for your building system, for example `Gnu make` keeps track of this for you, assuming that you wrote an appropriate `makefile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cd /usr/src/ ; make buildkernel NO_CLEAN=yes

Answer (score 1):

Use "make buildkernel KERNFAST=1".